# Using bridges don't hide using TOR, is it okay?

Tags: anonymity, bridge, deanonymization

Good day, Using bridges don't hide using TOR, is it okay?
If the question is stupid, sorry)
To check it - whoer helped. 
If it's normal situation, please, advise smth. that can hide it absolutely, thank you.

Comment: Yes. Bridges are meant to defeat block lists. Pluggable transports are meant to defeat DPI. Neither stops a keen observer from discerning that you're using Tor.

Comment: mm, are u sure, that there is no way to hide? ( And thank you for the answer